# How to copy emails that I delete into a separate folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 2016 for Windows 10.

I am trying to automatically copy emails that I delete into a separate folder (or perhaps overwrite "delete" with just the copy).

Before I get that far, a pre-requisite is to capture the delete event.

I found code on MSDN, which I inserted into `ThisOutlookSession`.

```vb
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem

Public Sub DeleteMail()
    Const strCancelEvent = "Application-defined or object-defined error"
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    myItem.Delete
    Exit Sub
  
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    If Err.Description = strCancelEvent Then
        MsgBox "The event was cancelled."
    End If
    'If you want to execute the next instruction
    Resume Next
    'Otherwise it will finish here
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_BeforeDelete(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Prompts the user before deleting an item
    Dim strPrompt As String
    'Prompt the user for a response
    strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to delete the item?"
    If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then
        'Don't delete the item
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When I delete an item (either by hitting the <kbd>del</kbd> key in the inbox or opening the item and clicking "Delete" on the ribbon), the item moves to the Deleted Items folder but I do not see a message box.

Comment: What causes DeleteMail sub to run? If it doesn't, myItem is never initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the BeforeDelete event is of limited use, as implemented with the DeleteMail code.

According to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861266.aspx "the DeleteMail() procedure should be called before the event procedure can be called by Outlook".

So your actions "... by hitting the "del" key in the inbox or opening the item and clicking "Delete" on the ribbon" are not valid.

You could investigate the NewInspector event to set myItem when you open an item and the SelectionChange event for the explorer.

You should be able to do what you want with ItemAdd 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx on the Deleted folder.

Comment: Thank you! While this wasn't perfect, I was able to hook into the itemadd event on the deleted items folder to make a copy of the mailitem as it is "deleted."