Register VBA event handler for Outlook deletion of appointment item
Public documentation of Outlook event handling is scarce. I'm trying to write a sub that will be executed when a calendar item is deleted. Below is what I'm trying now, which fails (the event never runs):
Module code
Dim myClass As New MyCalendar
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set myClass.myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.AppointmentItem")
End Sub

Class module (MyCalendar) code
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Private Sub myOlApp_BeforeDelete(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "prompt"
End Sub

All of the public examples I've found provide Outlook.Application as the class module example, not Outlook.AppointmentItem. But I'm trying to create an event hook specifically for deletion of an AppointmentItem.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sample code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.BeforeDelete. It is possible BeforeDelete is not usable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047210/1571407

If you have a followup, with new code, consider a new question since there is already an answer that may be  negated with an edited question.

CreateObject("Outlook.AppointmentItem") will fail - only Outlook.Application can be created. You can track appointments items either through Explorer.SelectionChange event to initialize the myOlApp variable (if you are tracking deletions from the Calendar folder) or track open Inspectors using Application.Inspectors.NewInspector event and set myOlApp variable to Inspector.CurrentItem  property.
Keep in mind that in both cases there can be more than one selected/displayed appointments, so you need to have a list of appointment items, not a single myOlApp variable.

Thanks, I have this worked to track SelectionChange events. But what do I need in order to add a trigger when the selected item is deleted? In other words, to inject code before the deletion takes place?

That is what BeforeDelete event is for.

But BeforeDelete can't attach to an inspector or an explorer object -- it needs to attach to an appointment item to work here. I have what might be the best solution worked out now -- when there is an Explorer.SelectionChange event, if the selection is an olAppointmentItem, it will add a BeforeDelete to that specific item, which will then be triggered in case the selected item is deleted. But it seems a fairly circuitous route to get the desired behavior.

@AdamJ.Kessel If you post reproducible working code in an answer, there could be feedback. You may post a question on Code Review if you think the code can be optimised. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

@AdamJ.Kessel - in case of an inspector, use Inspector.CurrentItem. In case of an Explorer, loop through the Explorer.Selection collection and attach the event handler to each item in the collection. Of course you'd need to release the previous items first, hence you need to have a collection/array of wrapper classes, not a single variable to store one item.
